# How to handle people camping your generator?

Tags: tribes-ascend

I've just come out of a terrible streak of terrible games where one side simply camped en-masse the other side's generators while people simply flew in, grabbed the flag and flew away. Without base defenses up classes like pathfinders don't have too much of a hard time simply going around in circles from flagpole to flagpole I imagine.

Since you can pick what team to be on and everybody tried to be on that one same side, we ended up taking 17 flags in a row across four different maps before I decided to spend my time otherwise.

What ended up happening is simply invisible dudes using sticky explosives around the generator. Technicians' sentries won't target them, technician's SMGs are no match for their explosion spam and even when I switched to more powerful classes such as Jaggernaut I had an extremely hard time with them camping bastards.

How can I cleanse my generator out of those pesky people? or am I fighting the wrong fight? I was *assuming* my teammates would bother with other stuff such as defending the flag or attempting to capture theirs but I guess that's not what was going on.

Comment: Don't you hate it when you're playing against people who are _better than you?_ It's infuriating. They must be cheesing it out or something.

Comment: Are you talking to yourself again?

Comment: The best course of action is usually to simply ignore the gen campers and go steal the enemy flag- the more people they have in your gen room, the less people will be able to stop your flag grabs.

Comment: Failing that, picking a heavy class to flush them out works as well. Doombringers in particular seem to be effective against Infiltrators.

Comment: I usually just went Juggernaut and launched Mortars into the room from outside their firing zone. Eventually they get low enough or run out to the point where they need to fight or die. On some maps that doesn't help because the Generator room is too large, but on smaller rooms it works pretty well.

Comment: Except that back in tribes 2 there was at least one map where destroying the generator meant ALL regular supply stations were offline so you couldn't mod into juggernaut armor. Or even medium.

Comment: @Shadur All regular supply stations do shut down in Ascend when the generator is off. You must die to change classes or travel to the midfield or something.

Comment: I just had this situation yesterday... and it was quite annoying, as I was the lone TCN defending and repairing against 2-3 heavies that would come. I would've liked at least 1 guy helping once in a while...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Preferred option: Let them waste time camping it. Focus on the flag stand instead.

First, an aside: Unlike earlier Tribes games, players spawn fully equipped in their chosen armor class. Since you don't have to visit an inventory station to gear up anymore, the generators tend to be *ignored* in high-level play. This is a controversial state of affairs that may see some changes in the coming months.

If a third of the other team wants to have a party in your gen room, let them. Switch to Pathfinder and chase enemy cappers instead. Switch to Doombringer and plant yourself on the flag, chaingunning down anyone who approaches. Switch to Soldier and harass approaching offense in your midfield. Cappers zooming around at 200 sanics or more aren't going to care about turrets, so neither should you.

### Alternate option: Switch to Brute or Juggernaut and clear out your base, but don't forget...

If there's [one thing the Brute is good at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NxW5.jpg) (and arguably, this is the *only* thing the Brute is good at) it's **close-quarters combat**. The Heavy Spinfusor and [Disco](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YH5MEyNuIM) [Grenades](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtcG7nXanpE) are great at taking down enemies indoors, but depending on the layout of the base and the number of hostiles, the Juggernaut's mortars may work better.

However, keep in mind that any players you kill will have respawned and skied back to your gen room in 20 or 30 seconds. With the regular repair gun, that's just enough time for you to get your generator back to 60% or so before the Raider you just killed turns the corner and blows it up again. If you don't have a Technician buddy to repair the generator for you and set up a couple turrets, you'll be right back where you started.

Personally, if I find myself in this situation, and none of my teammates are helping me set up a solid base defence, I'll just opt for option #1 above.

Comment: Skip the generator. Its normally a waste of time. Its usually a mix of inexperienced players and trolls who only focus on gens. The major exceptions are when custom servers use naked spawning and/or as a defensive strategy against vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't have many issues with INF as a tech, placing my turrets in the proper place, and stick a sensor just around the corner out of site so they trip it works pretty well. 
If there's more than one, I get on my Jugg or Raider and use (forget what it's called, brings them out of stealth though) I find jugg the best if more than 1.